# Error - while exporting a Sharepoint List (Export to Excel)

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, excel, export, list-view-threshold

Colleague of mine is facing the below issue while trying to export the SharePoint List which has more than 10 000 items. However I was able to export the complete List without any issues.

**Note:**
He is able to export another SharePoint list with 200 items and also add items.

> Error: An operation that uses the database driver could not be
>   completed. If the driver is a Microsoft driver, make sure the driver
>   file isn't damaged, and if it is, reintsall the driver by reinstalling
>   Microsoft Query. For other drivers, contact your database
>   administrator or driver vendor.

Comment: Time to figure out what is different between your machine and his machine. Do you guys have different versions of office? It seems to me like this is an Excel problem.. not a SharePoint problem.

Comment: If it is an Excel issue, it should not work for a smaller list right? But, It is working for a list with 100+ items...

Comment: We both are running on Office 2007 on Win7..

Answer (score 4):

Open the SharePoint 2010 Central Administration, Go to Application Management => Manage Web Applications and then select your web application. In the Ribbon, select the General Settings => Resource Throttling, There you can see the threshold limit 5000, edit the value as you need and save it.

Comment: I wonder how does it work for myself but not for my colleague. If it is something to do with threshold  setting then it should throw the same exception for myself too right?

Comment: also items are stored properly on the separate folders.

Comment: If you are an administrator, you will have a higher threshold than he does. I think the default admin threshold is as high as 20,000 or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link out it worked for me. I'm not sure about the trick in it but it worked and I was able to export the list items to excel by following this. I had 4000+ items in my list.

> 1. First off, copy this to a notepad file:
>
>    `http://[site]/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=[LISTID]&View=[VIEWID]&CacheControl`
> 2. Next, go to Site Actions–>Site Settings–>People and Groups–>All People.
> 3. Switch to Settings–>List Settings.
> 4. Select ‘List View’ at the bottom of the page. You will now see the ‘Edit View’ screen.
> 5. Copy and paste the URL of ‘Edit List View’ into the ‘.txt’ file.
> 6. Now, copy the corresponding IDs of ‘List’ and ‘View’ from the ‘List View’ URL into the URL specified in step one.
> 7. Open this URL and download the ‘owssvr.iqy’ file.
> 8. Finally, open this downloaded file in MS Excel.

http://www.sharepointserverrecovery.com/blog/troubleshooting-problems-when-exporting-sharepoint-list-data-to-excel-spreadsheet-and-fixing-database-corruption/

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue again, but the solution that has worked for me isn't the most obvious.

We have an 8000 record limit on SharePoint 2010 and this has happened with Views showing less than 5000 records, so in my case it wasn't the record limit.

When I receive this error

> Error: An operation that uses the database driver could not be
>   completed. If the driver is a Microsoft driver, make sure the driver
>   file isn't damaged, and if it is, reintsall the driver by reinstalling
>   Microsoft Query. For other drivers, contact your database
>   administrator or driver vendor

It has meant that somehow **the View is corrupt**.

To fix this, just create a new View. After you've created the new View, you can export this to Excel and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Something that worked for me with regards to this issue:

If you happen to add a filter on your view specifically on "Group by" Section, switch it back to None and save the view. Then try exporting again.

By the way, this is not a permanent solution. just a workaround if you really need to export now.