# Export to excel

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a list on which I am getting the below error:

"Cannot complete this action"

This error is showing up when I am doing Export To Excel from the ribbon menu

Let me know, 
Thanks.

Comment: First of all, I'd recommend you to check the ULS logs and add some error details in the question. "Cannot complete this action" is too general. Also, could you check if the other lists on your site/site collection have the same issue? If not, when what is the difference? How this list was created? Did you test this Export to Excel from other computers? Finally, it would be nice to know if you're using SP2010 or SP2013 :)

Comment: All lists are having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue. To solve it you need to verify 2 things

1. Your Url must be like
   `http://[site]/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=[LISTID]&View=[VIEWID]&CacheControl`
2. You must have MS-Excel installed on your system

Please refer this [Error - while exporting a SharePoint List (Export to Excel)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25868/error-while-exporting-a-sharepoint-list-export-to-excel)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Open the Internet Explorer
> 2. Tools
> 3. Internet Options
> 4. Advanced Settings
> 5. Scroll downwards and reach towards the section named as "Security"
> 6. CHECK FOR SERVER CERTIFICATE REVOCATION--which is by default checked
> 7. Unchecked it
> 8. Apply and Ok
> 9. Close all the internet explorers (IE) and open your SharePoint site in a new IE i.e. Browser/Explorer
> 10. You should be able to export the spreadsheet without any problems/issues.

http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/excel-cannot-connect-to-sharepoint-list.html

Comment: No, It didnt work